# Group and count user notifications

Tags: mysql, php, greatest-n-per-group

i have a notifications table like this:

[image]

i want to select all user 1 rows, but take only one row from rows with same parent id, and also have the count of those rows.

so i can show to user: 'jack and 3 more users have liked your post'.

many thanks

Comment: Please include sample output, and information on any other tables we would need to include to generate that.

Comment: Ah - I assumed we needed to retrieve the name tied to `rel_user_id` (to get "Jack" for "Jack and 3 more users liked your post").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should come close to meeting your need.

This assumes you want the `rel_user_id` from the most recently added row for a given `user_id` and `parent_id`, and that the row with the highest `id` should be the one most recently entered. If you want the rel_user_id with the highest value instead, .you can basically just use the `agg` subquery (changing `MAX(ID)` to `MAX(rel_user_id)`.

Also, I didn't worrying about the join to the `posts` table - I'm guessing that `parent_id` is the foreign key column, and you've got that; you should be able to get there from here.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT ntf.user_id
      ,ntf.parent_id
      ,ntf.rel_user_id
      ,agg.notification_count
  FROM (SELECT user_id, parent_id, COUNT(*) as notification_count, MAX(id) as max_id
          FROM notifications
         WHERE user_id = 1
         GROUP BY user_id, parent_id
       ) agg
         INNER JOIN notifications ntf ON (    agg.user_id = ntf.user_id
                                          AND agg.parent_id = ntf.parent_id
                                          AND agg.max_id = ntf.id
                                         )
 ORDER BY user_id, parent_id
;
```

The `agg` subquery gets us one row for each `user_id` and `parent_id`; we'll put the `WHERE` clause specifying which `user_id` you want here, to limit how many records we're grouping. This gets us the count of rows for the `user_id` and `parent_id` combo, and gets use the "most recent" `id`.

We then tie back to `notifications` with an `INNER JOIN` to get the `rel_user_id` from the indicated `id` row.

Here's a [db-fiddle.com link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eAbxJ41QkkQ9HcvH9YcBGn/0) showing the query in action, with the sample data you provided.